# Why is my SQL skipping over certain records when using INSERT INTO?

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, sql-insert

I'm writing a query to check when the first and last product was made during a shift. The code runs but skips over some records when moving through the dates.

I printed out the dates used in my while loop code using a msgbox function, to check if the program was skipping dates. This is working properly. 
I also wrote the SQL to insert the record for a specific date that i was missing and the record is inserted properly using this method. I am unable to figure out why it's skipping certain records if it works fine when i fully type it.

Code:

```
 Sub RunVroege()

'Declaration
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date

'Set a start and enddate for the records you want to copy
StartDate = #1/1/2020 6:00:00 AM#
EndDate = #5/29/2020 2:00:00 PM#

'06:00 - 14:00
StartVroege = StartDate
EindeVroege = DateAdd("h", 8, StartVroege)

'14:00 - 22:00
StartLate = EindeVroege
EindeLate = DateAdd("h", 8, StartLate)

'Empty the table "Vroege"
strSQL = "DELETE * FROM Vroege;"
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

'Empty the table "Late"
strSQL = "DELETE * FROM Late;"
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

'Insertion of a missing record -> works fine when used
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Vroege SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Combined data lakstraat] WHERE Date BETWEEN #01/06/2020 06:00:00# AND #01/06/2020 14:00:00#;"
    DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

'Insert all records into 2 tables with the first and last item produced that day, for each shift
Do While StartVroege < EndDate
    '06:00 - 14:00 shift
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Vroege SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Combined data lakstraat] WHERE Date BETWEEN #" & StartVroege & "# AND #" & EindeVroege & "#;"
    DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Vroege SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Combined data lakstraat] WHERE Date BETWEEN #" & StartVroege & "# AND #" & EindeVroege & "# ORDER BY Id DESC;"
    DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

    '14:00 - 22:00 shift
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Late SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Combined data lakstraat] WHERE Date BETWEEN #" & StartLate & "# AND #" & EindeLate & "#;"
    DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Late SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Combined data lakstraat] WHERE Date BETWEEN #" & StartLate & "# AND #" & EindeLate & "# ORDER BY Id DESC;"
    DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

    'Move to the next day
    StartVroege = DateAdd("d", 1, StartVroege)
    EindeVroege = DateAdd("d", 1, EindeVroege)
    StartLate = DateAdd("d", 1, StartLate)
    EindeLate = DateAdd("d", 1, EindeLate)

Loop

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What dates are being missed out?

Comment: I am guessing dates are not U.S./Access standard of mm/dd/yyyy and instead international dd/mm/yyyy. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: What i receive:
01/2/2020
01/3/2020
01/4/2020
01/13/2020

What i need to receive additionally:
01/06/2020
01/07/2020
01/08/2020
01/09/2020
01/10/2020

Comment: #Transform dd/mm/yyyy format tot mm/dd/yyyy for Access;

datetimeobject = datetime.datetime.strptime(startDate, '%d/%m/%Y')
startDate = datetimeobject.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
datetimeobject = datetime.datetime.strptime(endDate, '%d/%m/%Y')
endDate = datetimeobject.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')